# How can i put this in a for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to clean this up and put it in a for loop, 'couse i have more countries, but not much success... Can someone help?

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "hr") !== false){
include '/var/www/sites/footer/zohomerce/include/rabaho/tos/hr.php';

}
else if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "hu") !== false){
include '/var/www/sites/footer/zohomerce/include/rabaho/tos/hu.php';

}

else if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "it") !== false){
include '/var/www/sites/footer/zohomerce/include/rabaho/tos/it.php';

}

else if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "ro") !== false){
include '/var/www/sites/footer/zohomerce/include/rabaho/tos/ro.php';

}
```

Comment: Hi Vedran you can break it down to 2 lines really...1st ::    $a = Server_request path and strip last letters or so...  2nd::        include '/var/www/sites/footer/zohomerce/include/rabaho/tos/  + $a  + ".php"   ........     no loop needed.

Comment: Your method of detecting the language string isn't ideal... What if you have a file called ... I dunno... `robot.php`? Then your code thinks the request was for the `ro` language!

Comment: Could you show general REQUEST_URI structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with country codes and loop through it to find match

```
$array = array('hu', 'it', 'ro', 'hr');

foreach( $array as $country ) {
    if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $country ) !== false ){
       include '/var/www/sites/footer/zohomerce/include/rabaho/tos/' . $country . '.php';
       break;
    }
}
```

If URI is http://homesite.com, it will contain 'it' and will force false search result.
So if URI is like http://homesite.com/it/page.php, you need to search `/it/` instead of `it`

Answer (score 0):

The author's idea of checking only the presence of value is flawed. What if the URL contains the value but with different semantics?

I would suggest looking both at position and language.

```
// Explode the url into parts
$urlParts = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// allowed values
$array = ['hu', 'it', 'ro', 'hr'];

// here I assume that language will always be in the 1st position
// e.g. yoursite.com/hu/whatever
//      yoursite.com/it
// if value is not provided, use hu
$countryStr = isset($urlParts[1]) ? $urlParts[1] : 'hu';

// Checking if value is within allowed values to prevent nasty stuff
if ($countryStr, $array) 
{
    include '/var/www/sites/footer/zohomerce/include/rabaho/tos/' . $countryStr . '.php';
}
```

There is also the `$_GET[]` array if you are passing the value as URL parameter

Comment: This is the logic i need, but code is not working for some reason...

Comment: Please share var_dump() contents of $urlParts and provide the error messages.